# .bat file / script to convert various file types to .mp3 with FFMPEG

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch-file

I have a folder with various media files such as `.m4a`, `.aac`, `.mp4`, etc. and I want to invoke FFMPEG to convert them all to `.mp3` using the basic FFMPEG command `ffmpeg -i myfile.m4a myfile.mp3`.

Can you show me a basic example of what this `.bat` text file would look like? I would like to iterate each media file using a type of wildcard so that it automatically runs.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill uncalled for

Comment: Not its not. It is standard policy on [su].

Comment: David’s comment is absolutely appropriate. [SU] has [over 4,000 questions about loops](https://superuser.com/search?q=loop+is%3Aq), including [over 250 about FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/search?q=loop+ffmpeg+is%3Aq).  We have spent years building a library / knowledge base of reusable answers, and we expect our users to search through that library and try *something* before asking a new question.  The [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) help page explains this.

Comment: @DaveM: [Please don’t make and/or approve trivial/cosmetic edits to recently closed questions](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13646/354511).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (If you have all files in media type, no other types of files)

```
@echo off
Pushd "Filepath"
for %%a in (*) do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%~fa" "%%~na.mp3"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much a lot!